# Xcode 5 & IOS 7 localization fallback language

Tags: ios7, localization, xcode5, default, fallback

I basically have functioning localization (whithout base), but I'm curious with regards to a specific case.

IOS stores the latest used languages on a device, but what if:

my application supports both Dutch and English and the app is also available in non-Dutch or English speaking countries. If a user has never used English or Dutch as a device language, what language will be on display in my app?

I naturally prefer to have the English language to be displayed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS will pick the one which is placed higher in the list of languages under:

`Settings > General > International > Languages`

For example consider the devices with language lists:

Device A

- French
- Italian
- English
- Dutch
- Turkish

Device A (currently set to French) will display your app in **English**. Because English is placed higher than Dutch.

Device B

- Japanese
- German
- French
- Dutch
- Turkish
- English

Device B (currently set to Japanese) will display your app in **Dutch**. Because Dutch is placed higher than English.

If user never changed language settings, default order of these languages depends on the targeted market of the device.